# Disable replication for some MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, replication

I have a PHP script that execute a lot of queries (multiples `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`) in order to `UPDATE` one and unique table.

I would like to skip replication on the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` and only replicate the `UPDATE` query.

How can I achieve that ? I tried to disable the `mysql_bin_log` but it doesn't work (the mysql user has SUPER privilege)s:

```
mysql_query("SET sql_log_bin=0;");
$i = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin';"));
var_dump($i['Value']); // Return : ON
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you us the actual code what you want to achieve...?

Comment: As I said, I just want to skip replication on some mysql queries executed via php. I believe one way to achieve that was to disable binary log but I didn't succeed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use replicate-wild-ignore-table=NotRep% and create your tables with NotRep prefix.

`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE NotRepTableForSmthn (...)`

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-wild-ignore-table for details.